# modrewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've one page on my website with the following type of links:

http://www.qblza.com.br/anuncio_detalhes.php?ida=231&title=capa-para-iphone-4-game-boy

I would like to rewrite the urls in the following format:

http://www.qblza.com.br/231/title=capa-para-iphone-4-game-boy

I've tried thousands of modrewrite generators but no one is working on my website.
The last one generated the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.gobig.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Is the rewrite module enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic htaccess you need :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /anuncio_detalhes.php?ida=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

- you've got two parameters : `http://www.qblza.com.br/[param1]/[param2]`
- they're both required
- `[param1]` will accept only numbers (one or more) : `([0-9]+)`
- `[param2]` will accept numbers, letters and `-` (one or more) : `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`
- the final `/` is optional

Note : please remember an htaccess file won't magically change your old urls. You need to use the `http://www.qblza.com.br/[param1]/[param2]` pattern, and htaccess will redirect those 'false' urls to real ones.

Comment: Hey samsamX, thank you for all your explanation. I'm going to try it right now! Thanks!!!

Comment: I just updated my .htacsess but now it's not working...when I click on link I'm getting a 404 page not found...

Comment: For debug, change `[L]` tag into `[L,R=301]` tag, this will rewrite the url in the browser, look if it's the one you really want (copy/paste origin and result urls here please)

Comment: This is what I get: 
    http://www.qblza.com.br/232/samsung-duos-camera-2-mp-redes-sociais-2-chips-bluetooth

You can try it here: www.qblza.com.br/listagem.php

Comment: Seems like your `mod_rewrite` isn't enabled. Please check it, and look if your htaccess file is on the right place (in the root folder)

Comment: right..I'll check wiht my hosting company! Thank you for all your help!